# Openssl is not working, and directory /etc/ssl is missing

Tags: linux, bash, ssl, openssl

We are working on a red hat linux server, and we can apply `openssl version` and `openssl` will get you inside openssl shell-like `Openssl>`

But there is no directory `/etc/ssl/` and we are getting the following failure when we try to connect:

```
[<username>@<pc name> etc]$ openssl s_client -port 31114 -host <ipaddress> -ssl3 -quiet -crlf
904:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:530:
```

It is not working, nothing is working in openssl on the server? what shall we do?

we are sure that openssl is installed:

```
[root@<pc name> ~]# yum list |grep openssl
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
openssl.i686                             0.9.8e-12.el5          installed
openssl.x86_64                           0.9.8e-12.el5          installed
openssl-devel.i386                       0.9.8e-12.el5          installed
openssl-devel.x86_64                     0.9.8e-12.el5          installed
openssl097a.i386                         0.9.7a-9.el5_2.1       installed
openssl097a.x86_64                       0.9.7a-9.el5_2.1       installed
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the -servername option?  Does tls work via the switch -tls1?  Have you tried just creating the /etc/ssl directory yourself?

Comment: @tale852150 
I can create the directory ssl, but I think it is not the good way (it should be automatically created maybe), where is this -servername option ? how can I check the -tls1 thing?thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [<username>@<pc name> etc]$ openssl s_client -port 31114 -host <ipaddress> -ssl3 -quiet -crlf
> 904:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:530:
> ```

It is likely that your unknown server does not allow SSL 3.0 at all since this old protocol version is considered insecure for a long time. And if the protocol is denied by the server the handshake will fail as in this case. This is unrelated to the existence of the `/etc/ssl` directory.

Answer (score 0):

`yum whatprovides /etc/ssl/` shows which package provides this dir.

In `EL6` it is `ca-certificates-2015`. Install that package.